# SQL query gone wrong

Tags: mysql, sql, view, where-clause

what am i doing wrong here  ? This query results in 0 rows . the status table is an int type

```
CREATE OR replace view ACTIVE_GROUPS AS
SELECT id, name, status
FROM test1.group
WHERE status != 2 group by id
```

Comment: Well, you're picking an arbitrary (or indeterminate) name and status for every id.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't mean to put .group at the end of test1?
Also you may not need `group by id`, it depends what you're trying.

```
SELECT id, name, status
FROM test1
WHERE status != 2 group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    IF if exists(select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS where TABLE_NAME='ACTIVE_GROUPS')
BEGIN
 ALTER  view ACTIVE_GROUPS AS
    SELECT id, name, status
    FROM test1.group
    WHERE status != 2 group by

END
ELSE
    CREATE  view ACTIVE_GROUPS AS
    SELECT id, name, status
    FROM test1.group
    WHERE status != 2 group by id
BEGIN
END
```